# Masking the value When NgModel is loaded from an NgFor

Tags: angular

When my page is loaded, a call is made to the API, which returns a JSON that has a deeply nested array that is being accessed in the HTML via ngFor.

The value is a number, which automatically removes trailing zeros. My goal is to re-add trailing zeros.

The HTML looks like:

```
 <th>
   <input type="number" step="any" class="input-padding input-box modal-input" [(ngModel)]="segment.number">
 </th>
```

I have tried using `(change)` which does fire when the ngModel is loaded, but I have not been able to reset the value to have trailing zeros.

Comment: I quite don't get your question. So you get the string data like "0056" within your json response and it is being removed by your input element. And you want to add it back. Is that your problem?

Comment: I am getting a Number back like 15.2, what I would like is to convert that value to a string and get something like 15.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

If you want to mask the value of `ngModel` attribute, then you may do

`this._segment = this.decPipe.transform(value, '1.2')` in your `segment` setter method.

So you need to add `setter/getter` for `segment` property which will take care of automatic conversion.

```
export class AppComponent  {
 private _segment;

  get segment () {
     return this._segment;
  }

  set segment(value){
   this._segment = this.decPipe.transform(value, '1.2')
  }

  constructor(private decPipe : DecimalPipe){
    this.segment = '15.2'
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-pipes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Original answer :**

If I have understood your problem correctly, you want to display `number` with two digit `decimal`. You can use `number` pipe for that

```
<input type="number" value="{{segment | number: '1.2'}}" >
```

Comment: Why it does not work? It displays 15.2 as 15.20. That is what you wanted right?

Comment: No it does not display 15.2 as 15.20, hence it was clever, but did not work.

Comment: See this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-pipes?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Ok, you can do the formatting within your component file itself instead of doing from template. Check updated answer.

Comment: @maxsands1503 Did you try out that? That should work for you.

Comment: I ended up doing it in the component file. It is pretty hacky considering how deeply nested the array is, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because it's a **number**.
Please use a **string** *("0123")* instead

Comment: I switched the input type from string to number and nothing. Converting the ngModel value to a string is what I want to do, but I do not know how to.

Comment: What I meant was your json should contain the value as a string not number ("0123" not 0123). If you have access do the changes in the place where you generate the json

Comment: We would really prefer not making changes to the API. There is definitely a way to do this in typescript. We just want to add trailing zeros, so 15.2 becomes 15.20.